# Moq to echo IEnumerable back out returning empty?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to set up a mock object so that it just echoes the one of the input variables back to the caller.

```
_resultThrottler = new Mock<IResultThrottler>();
_resultThrottler
    .Setup(x => x.Throttle(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<ProductResult>>(), It.IsAny<Guid>()))
    .Returns((IEnumerable<ProductResult> input, Guid resultSetId) => input );
```

However when it's actually called the output is always empty.

```
var throttledResults = _resultThrottler.Throttle(results, resultSetId).ToList();
```

What might I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**: as requested:

```
public interface IResultThrottler
{
    IEnumerable<TType> Throttle<TType>(IEnumerable<TType> collectionToThrottle,
        Guid sessionId) where TType : ProductResult;
}
```

The full initialisation sequence for the variable `results` is rather convoluted, but in the tests it's going in as an object of type `System.Collections.Generic<IEnumerable<(type that inherits from ProductResult)>>` of length 5, and coming out of the mocked object with length zero.

Comment: Just for completeness, can you add the declaration/initialization of `results`?

Comment: And the definition of `IResultThrottler.Throttle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Moq didn't like that I was trying to mock using the inherited type, rather than the actual specific type.

I've moved the code to take a type parameter -

```
public class ResultThrottlerStubBuilder<TType> where TType : ProductResult
{
    private Mock<IResultThrottler> _resultThrottler;
    public IResultThrottler Build()
    {
        _resultThrottler = new Mock<IResultThrottler>();
        _resultThrottler
            .Setup(x => x.Throttle(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<TType>>(), It.IsAny<Guid>()))
            .Returns((IEnumerable<TType> input, Guid resultSetId) => input );

        return _resultThrottler.Object;
    }
}
```

And changed the test code to match, and the tests now pass. Thanks commenters for nudging my thinking in the right direction :-)

Comment: Ah yep, those are different types (`IEnumerable<Base>` and `IEnumerable<Derived>`) as far as Moq is concerned, and so requires different setups.

Comment: Annoying that they're different enough to require the specific setup like that, but not different enough that if you set it up on the base class you get null reference exceptions as you would if they'd been declared with completely wrong types.